# Differences between Pthread in C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, posix, ada

So I was able to pass an Ada function using Ada_function'Address to a C_function. Here is the C function:

```
void Create_Process(int * status, void * function) {
    pthread_t new_thread;

    //creating function with the given function and no arguments.
    *status = pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, function, NULL);
}
```

This worked perfectly fine. My problem is when I try to use this same function in C++. It fails at compiling with the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
*status = pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, function, NULL);
```

Is there any reason that this works / compiles in C but not C++?

Comment: Possibly because C and C++ are different languages? Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics.

Comment: You should not be treating pointers to functions as pointers to objects — they aren't guaranteed to be the same size, even in C (though they commonly are the same size).  C++ is fussier about such issues; you have to explicitly convert `void *` to the desired type, whereas C does that casually for you — one of the reasons C++ programmers are leery of C at times.  Succinctly, there's lots of C code that is not valid C++ code; your function is one example of such code.

Comment: Your C function doesn’t seem to add any value over just using `pthread_create()` directly. In fact, you lose the thread id `pthread_t`.

Comment: @SimonWright Yes I know that.This rest of the function is not EXACTLY the same. This was more of for clarity purposes.

Comment: Your compiler is actually obligated to issue a diagnostic message about this in C, provided you have the correct prototype for `pthread_create()` visible when you call it. There is no implicit conversion from `void*` to function-pointer type, this is a constraint violation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the point of passing address to Ada function into pthread instead of using native Ada threading (tasking)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implicit type conversions in C++ are much more strict than in C. The `void * function` parameter can't be used as function pointer in C++ or C...

You need `void* (*function)(void*)` in your function prototype.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [KIIV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5271927/kiiv) implicit type conversions in C++ are much more strict than in C.

`void* (*function) (void*)`

This is a pointer to a function which takes one `void*` argument and returns `void*`.

To get rid of your errors in C++, change your function to return `void *`, and pass it without type-casting it. The return from the thread function can be a simple return `NULL` if you don't care about the value.

There are various other issues with using this C library directly from C++; in particular, for portability, the thread entry function should be `extern "C"`. Good practice should be using the standard C++ thread library (or Boost's implementation, if you're stuck with a pre-2011 version of the language).

Comment: How would I create a thread that runs a function using the c++ standard thread library when all i have is the address ( pointer ) to the function that is passed in from Ada?